# Spectral radius of infinite substochastic upper triangular matrix

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, matrices, markov-chains, spectral-radius

Let $M$ be a Markov chain on $\{0, 1, 2, \dots\} \cup \{\delta\}$, where $\Pr(i \to j) > 0$ for $i, j \in \mathbb{N}$ only if $j > i$, and $\Pr(\delta \to \delta) = 1$. This represents a birth-process with possible extinction at each step.

The probability $\Pr(\text{particle survives starting at 0}) = 1 - \Pr(\delta \text{ is reached starting from 0})$ is equal to $\lim_{n \to \infty} (P^n \mathbf{1})_0$, where $P$ the transition matrix of the Markov chain on $\mathbb{N}$. That is, $P$ is a substochastic matrix with

$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty p_{ij} \leq 1, \quad \text{for every $i \in \mathbb{N}$.}$$

What can we say about $\lim_{n \to \infty} (P^n \mathbf{1})_0$?

An initial thought is that it depends on the spectral radius of $P$, so a related questions is: what is known about the spectral radius for doubly infinite substochastic matrices?

Comment: I think you just need the hitting probability of $\delta$. There is a standard recurrence formula to compute that. The fact that your matrix is super-triangular should make that straightforward enough.

Comment: The recurrence for the hitting probabilities (from state $i$) is an infinite "forward recurrence" that essentially boils down to P^n 1. Do you have some method in mind for computing this recurrence?

Comment: My point is that calculating a spectral radius for an infinite matrix, you need to decide on the Banach space and all sorts of fancy stuff, whereas what you need is just the single number, the hitting probability. I don't have a method other than writing down the equations (for a vector) and staring at them, but I still think this is preferable to computing powers of a matrix.

Comment: Could you be more precise? What do you want to know about the survival probability? Also, what makes you think that it might be connected with the spectral radius of $P$?